# Django reportlab - Print current page (admin console) to PDF

Tags: python, django, pdf, reportlab

What I am trying to accomplish is to allow users to view information in the django admin console and allow them to save and print out a PDF of the information infront of them based upon how ever they sorted/filtered the data.

I have seen a lot of documentation on report lab but mostly for just drawing lines and what not. How can I simply output the admin results to a PDF? If that is even possible. I am open to other suggestions if report lab is not the ideal way to get this done.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Better use some kind of [html2pdf](http://www.xhtml2pdf.com/) because you already have html there.

Answer (score 1):

If html2pdf doesn't do what you need, you can do everything you want to do with ReportLab.  Have a look at the ReportLab manual, in particular the parts on Platypus.  This is a part of the ReportLab library that allows you to build PDFs out of objects representing page parts (paragraphs, tables, frames, layouts, etc.).